# Subdomain 404 Errors Isuue

Tags: seo, google-search-console, subdomain, 404

I have a dual language news website. I have found a number of 404 errors in example.com which URLs should be in en.example.com, these are actually English content but showing in example.com (Bengali) for this reason 404 errors found in Google Search Console/Webmaster Tools.

This my first experience from Google Search Console. At this time, how will I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Check your site for bad links.

Comment: I have checked but did not get these types of URLs at Bengali Version but with these URLs have News on English Version.

Comment: I only mentioned checking the links because we have all goofed up from time to time. Google follows links. If you see 404 errors for pages that should not exist, then there really is no problem unless... you guessed it... you have bad links. ;-) Of course bad links on other sites pointing to yours will do the same thing. Just make sure your site is right. Nothing you can do about the sites you do not control. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using *relative* URLs instead of *absolute* URLs for **example.com**. For example, if you are trying to link to **en.example.com/page-is-in-here**, make sure that your link (or Navigation Menu Link) from example.com is like

```
<a href="http://en.example.com/page-is-in-here">Go to en.example.com page</a> - Absolute
```

and not

```
<a href="/page-is-in-here">Go to en.example.com page</a> - Relative
```

In the search console reports for **example.com**, Google believe that **/page-is-in-here** is actually **example.com/page-is-in-here** and that is probably why you are getting the 404 errors.

Another probably reason is that when you switch language make sure the requested URLs are absolute and not relative, if you are doing this via JavaScript, make sure that the script is generating absolute url.

Answer (score 0):

> I have found a number of 404 errors in example.com which URLs should be in en.example.com, ...

If this is a 100% fact in your situation, then you need to implement permanent redirects. You can set up automatic redirects with your server software to automatically redirect guests from example.com/englishpage/whatever to en.example.com/englishpage/whatever.

Just ensure that when you are done, you try accessing your old link in webpagetest.org or similar tool to ensure the redirect is in place. From a web browser's point of view, the redirect page will normally have HTTP code 301 which stands for "Moved Permanently".

If there are URLs that just aren't supposed to be there anymore on your server, then use the HTTP 410 status code to represent "Gone" so search engines don't keep scanning the page.

As for the remaining HTTP 404 error pages, just fix the URLs so there is content.